# How to make a django model "commentable", "likeable" and "rateable"

Tags: python, django, mixins

I am using Django 2.0.8 and Python 3.5 for a project. I have different models in my project, some of which, I want to allow commenting on - with both the object (e.g. a blogpost) and comments to the blogpost being likeable.

I am using the [threaded comments django app](https://github.com/HonzaKral/django-threadedcomments) to provide commenting functionality.

Assuming I have a model Foo (see below):

```
from django.db import models
from django.conf import settings

class Foo(models.Model):
    owner = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, blank=False, null=False, default=1, on_delete = models.PROTECT)
    # ...


class Likeable():
    pass

class Rateable():
    pass
```

How could I use mixins (or any other mechanism for that matter), to make the object Foo "commentable" (i.e. an object which can be commented upon), "likeable" (i.e. an object which can be commented upon) and "rateable" (i.e. an object which can be rated?)- bearing in mind that comments on an objects may be BOTH liked and rated.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

According to [django documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/es/2.1/ref/contrib/contenttypes/) , you can achieve this using the **Content types Framework**. `ContentType` is a generic model that permits you to track all the models included in `INSTALLED_APPS` using for that their `app_label`, `model_name` and `pk`. The way it works is easy:

### Your generic `Comment` model

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.contenttypes.fields import GenericForeignKey
from django.contrib.contenttypes.models import ContentType
from django.conf import settings


class Comment(models.Model):
    # Generic relation fields
    content_type = models.ForeignKey(ContentType, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    object_id = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    content_object = GenericForeignKey('content_type', 'object_id')
    # Model specific fields
    author = models.ForeignKey(
        settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE
    )
    comment = models.TextField()
    created = models.DatetimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    # ...
```

### Your reusable generic relation model. The best way is using abstract model classes or mixins. For example, using abstract models:

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.contenttypes.fields import GenericRelation


class Commentable(models.Model):
    comments = GenericRelation(Comment)

    class Meta:
        abstract = True
```

### Your `Commentable` model:

```
from django.db import models


class Foo(Commentable, Likeable, ...):
    # your stuff
```

### How to use it:

```
# Add a new comment to Foo
foo = new Foo()
foo.save()
foo.comments.create(author=author, comment="Your comment")

# Retrieve all comments from an specific user no matter the base model
comments = Comment.objects.filter(author=author)
```

---

**EDIT** As @ozren1983 said, each approach has its own downsides, but this is the standard way to do it.

The main advantages are:

- You can retrieve all the comments (for example) made in all your commentable models in just one query. Using the approach of having a comment, like, etc table per model, you would need to concatenate a query per model. This could be problematic and a bit challenging if you have a lot of models or if you want to merge the results and order them, for example.
- Just one table per functionality (comments, likes) implies just one database migration in case of change. This could be key if your database is huge.

The main disadvantage is the lack of integrity checks of this generic relationship in database. But if you plan to use the django ORM **strictly**, nothing should be broken.

---

**BONUS:** Another approach that many projects use is inheriting the models (one to one relationship) from an specific one called `Item` or `Thread`. Then, you can add all the comments, likes, etc functionalities to this model. This is called multi-table inheritance. An example:

```
from django.db import models


class Thread(models.Model):
    pass

class Comment(models.Model):
    # Relation with thread
    thread = models.ForeignKey(
        Thread,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        related_name="comments"
    )
    # Model specific fields
    author = models.ForeignKey(
        settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE
    )
    comment = models.TextField()
    created = models.DatetimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    # ...

class Foo(Thread):
    pass
```

Unlike using the generic relationships, the main advantage of this method is that, this way, you have database integrity checks.

The main disadvantage is that your database structure could become complex.

Comment: I am based in Europe. As a result of [GDPR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/General_Data_Protection_Regulation) requirements, the ability to extract/purge all comments for a user becomes a necessity, which makes the **generic relationship** model attractive - even if it is at the cost of slightly slower queries.

Comment: How would the Foo object be interrogated for comments, likes etc in the case of the **multi-table inheritance** example?

Comment: Same way, using ```foo.comments.filter(...)```

Comment: just to clarify, with the first example you gave (for the Foo class). Given an instance of Foo `foo`, would `foo.comments` return a list of all comments associated with the `foo` instance? (i.e. for all users).

Comment: I added your generic relationship approach, however I am not facing issues making it possible to add comments inline via the admin UI.

when adding "comments" to the fields property, I end up with "model form as it is a non-editable field"

Answer (score 2):

Based on my experience and recommendations in [Two scoops of Django](https://www.twoscoopspress.com/products/two-scoops-of-django-1-11), I would advise against using `GenericForeignKey` and `GenericRelation`. Two big downsides of that approach are:

- slow queries
- danger of data corruption

Instead, I would use following approach. Let's say you have 3 models:

```
class User(models.Model):
    username = models.CharField(max_length=255)

class Author(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)

class Post(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    author = models.ForeignKey(Author)
```

Add abstract `Like` model, and use it as base class for other models that will implement liking functionality.

```
class Like(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    date_created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    class Meta:
        abstract = True

class AuthorLike(Like):
    author = models.ForeignKey(Author)

class PostLike(Like):
    post = models.ForeignKey(Post)
```

Similarly, add abstract `Rating` model and use it as a base class:

```
class Rating(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    rate = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField()
    date_created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    class Meta:
        abstract = True

class AuthorRating(Rating):
    author = models.ForeignKey(Author)

class PostRating(Rating):
    post = models.ForeignKey(Post)
```

You can use same approach to enable liking and rating to the Comments model you are using:

```
from threadedcomments.models import ThreadedComment

class ThreadedCommentRating(Rating):
    threadedcomment = models.ForeignKey(ThreadedComment)

class ThreadedCommentLike(Like):
    threadedcomment = models.ForeignKey(ThreadedComment)
```

Answer (score 1):

The `django-contrib-comments` app, according to documentation, makes use of  `GenericForeignKey`, meaning its own model can create a relation to any other model in your project.

A simple solution would be to just copy that existing functionality, creating your own Like/Rate application based on the same concept (i.e. storing the Like/Rate models in that application's models).

I think you would get very far starting out by forking the https://github.com/django/django-contrib-comments codebase.

(I assume you have searched and failed to find an already existing application that already does this).